# grpc_csharp_ext.x64 Error loading native library. Not found in any of the possible locations

Tags: c#, dll, grpc, filenotfoundexception

When published to azure, grpc_csharp_ext.x64.dll and x86 version get copied to azure web app root directory but not the bin directory.  That results in following error

```
Error loading native library. Not found in any of the possible locations: 
C:\home\site\wwwroot\bin\grpc_csharp_ext.x86.dll,
C:\home\site\wwwroot\bin\runtimes/win-x86/native\grpc_csharp_ext.x86.dll,
C:\home\site\wwwroot\bin\../..\runtimes/win-x86/native\grpc_csharp_ext.x86.dll
```

The same error also occurs for x64.dll version.

When both dlls manually copied to the bin folder then the website works.

when I publish local folder, the dlls not published to root or bin folders.